# Is it possible to set DB row-level permissions for users?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, authorization

I am looking for a database for my project and want to try a new one that I didn't work before with to learn and to find advantages for the project. One of the favourites I want to try is Postgres, but not necessarily.

One of features I'd like to see if possible is setting row-level permissions for users that are authenticated and authorized in my system.

Say, I have a user `john` who is a regular `user`. Being a regular user John can only create/update his own rows but not others, and have read access to some views in the database.

I know I can make these permissions work on app level but if it were available in the database, I'd like to try it out.

Are there common database that have this feature out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is indeed possible and well supported in PostgreSQL 9.5 (as well as earlier versions to some degree).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html

It's called Row Security.

A couple things to keep in mind:

1. It is flexible
2. you can use the `current_user` variable for access control
3. it relies on an actual postgresql user

Sometimes in app development it's not practical to have a separate database user for every type of authenticated user on your web application.  There are other ways to handle this.

In some of my applications we set postgresql variables (`set command`) when the connection is picked up by a web request.  These variables keep track of who is authenticated.  Then we use views to control access based on these variables.  Comment if you'd like more details on this practice.